# can't show image from database after i close the windowTab or i restart my front end server (react.js, express.js)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, backend, web-frontend

im using react.js with express.js,
So im uploading the image into my sequelize everything working fine but once i close the window tab or restart the front end server then the image is no longer there and im getting this error `GET blob:http://localhost:3000/1ee4299a-1110-42f7-b158-a0d856b77040 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`This code is in my form.jsx file`

```
  <input type="file" multiple accept="image/png" onChange={e => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FILES, payload: { filesVal: e.target.files } })} />

case ACTIONS.FILES:
return { ...state, Files: URL.createObjectURL(action.payload.filesVal[0]) }

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        Files: "",  
    })

const allData = { Image: state.Files }

            fetch("/api/sendDataForm", {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(allData)
            }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
```

so here everything works fine and i get the data in my sequelize database

so in backend i have this, this is the server.js for my backend

`servers.js file`

```
const user = reportsDb.define("Report", {
    Image: DataTypes.STRING
})

app.post("/api/sendDataForm", async (req, res) => {

    const { Deparment, Author, RoomNumber, Arrival, Priority, Report, CommonAreas, CommonAreasAndRooms, RoomCheckBox, LocationCheckBox, Location, Date, Time, Status, Image } = req.body
    const reports = await user.create({
        Image: Image
    })

    res.json({ "message": "New form has been submited. Saving data to the database" })

    await reports.reload()
})
```

At this point i have everything in my database

now im sending those data to my `Reports.jsx file` and the with props im sending the data to my child component `ChildReports.jsx`

`Reports.jsx file`

```
{allData.map(data => {
               console.log(data.Image)
               return (
                  <div key={data.id} >
                     <ChildReports
                        Image={data.Image}
                     />

                  </div>
               )
            })}
```

`ChildReports.jsx file`

```
{Image !== "" &&
    <div className={reportsCss.imageDiv}>
         <img src={Image} alt="image" />
           </div>
        }
```

so at this point everythig working fine and i can show my image but once i close the window tab in the broswer or i restart my front end server then i can't show that image anymore and im geting  the error `GET blob:http://localhost:3000/1ee4299a-1110-42f7-b158-a0d856b77040 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` i have try to google it but i didn't found anything

Thanks for your time reading this and helping me out!